# Android- how to get a scroll view to take up the full width of the screen?

Tags: java, android, width, scrollview

Im trying to get my scroll view to take up the whole width of the screen. I used match parent on the row its on and on the scroll view it self. However it still wont expand to the full width of the screen. Ive tried other stuff like fill:viewport but that didnt work as well.
Link to screenshot of current output https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EUlE.jpg
I put a background color of pink on the scroll view

XML code for scrollview and the row its on

```
 <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:background="@color/corn"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/completeTable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </TableRow>
```

Code for the table row im inserting into the scrollview(dont think this is the problem

```
    <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/task"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="@string/deleteItem" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Why do you have a table row outside your scrollview?

Comment: Im using table layout for the whole application(consistency). The table row shouldnt be a problem should it?

Comment: Wow that was the problem. Thanks man. you know why the scroll view didnt take up the whole table row though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a `LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout`/`FrameLayout` for your application screens!

I think your problem here was because you had many tablerows in your main `TableLayout` that englobes your `ScrollView`. You had your `TableRow`set on `wrap_content` which probably squished your `ScrollView`!